# Verify if csv file is updated successfully

Tags: java

I have trouble while updating a csv file (write), if there are any exception thrown such as system power may be also off or another app's reading the file.
In this case, the reading side cannot judge whether csv file is updated completely or not.
Is there any technique (format) to solve this problem ?
I have research and see that we can add some keyword such as EOF(xxxx) if the file is updated successfully, but is there any idea that more standardize plz?

Answer (score 2):

Try appending a checksum or CRC to the end of the file. This would allow you to detect whether an error occurred while the file was being written.

When you are reading back the file, just compute the checksum, and compare it against the saved checksum. If they are different, the file is bad.

This however would make the file difficult to modify by hand. I recommend this only if the file is not meant to be created or modified by hand.

Edit:

A checksum is different than a CRC though you'll hear the terms used interchangeably erroneously.  A checksum is just taking all the data in some unit of data, and adding it all together.  A CRC takes the data and performs bit manipulation on it. A checksum is easier, and faster to compute, but results in more false positives than a CRC and so is less robust.

Both are used to verify data integrity, and is usually used in data transfer over a network.  It works well for this purpose because you're "streaming" data from RAM to disk. If an error occurs in transfer, a checksum is a natural way to check this.

Create a [CheckedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CheckedOutputStream.html). It will maintain a checksum as you are writing bytes out to your CSV. Once you've finished writing the file, retrieve the checksum from the CheckedOutputStream, and write it to the file. Then close the stream.

Use a [CheckedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CheckedInputStream.html) when reading data back. Then compare the checksum calculated when reading to the checksum stored in the file. If they are the same, its extremely likely the file has no errors. I say extremely likely because with a checksum or CRC there is a very miniscule possibility of false positives.

Comment: Hi Will, that sounds good, but could you give me some links on how to insert checksum in file plz, for the research result on webs just shows that "A Checksum is used for error checking while transferring a file" (http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/ChecksumCRC32.shtml), but not checking when a file throws exception while updating.
I'm kinda new to the file checksum, tks!

Comment: The link you've gave looks like it explains everything pretty clearly and even has a code example. Hopefully with my thorough explanation above things are more clear now?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Will, but my trouble isn't for checking transfer csv file, it's just for noting if a csv file is updated completely. Just like adding a mark to tell that the file is ok.

Comment: Adding any mark at all to the end of the file will tell you that. If the mark is missing, the file is bad. Otherwise its good.